# Extra Space Between DIVs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, html, space

I'm working on a landing page in Wordpress that consists of two main components:

1. A vertically and horizontally centered DIV (accomplished with Jquery)
2. A series of buttons with a rollover effect (accomplished with JqueryUI)

While both of these components seem to be functioning well, there is an extra space between the buttons that I can't seem to find in the HTML editor, which can be seen [here](http://adrienneadams.org/landing/). The spaces between the "Main Site," "Mobile," and "Donate" buttons are noticeably larger than the space between the title and the first button.

Using inspect element in Chrome, the line following the `</div>` tag for each button contains a `" "` , which I think might be responsible for the extra space, but I can't find it in the Wordpress HTML editor. I've also downloaded a WP disable wpautop-type plugin, but it hasn't removed the space.

Finally, when I paste the HTML and associated CSS into [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/sJfKB/), the extra space dissapears. I'm assuming the issue is with Wordpress' automatic formatting. However, I can't figure out what function is adding the space or how to remove it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might want to start by cleaning up the errors (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fadrienneadams.org%2Flanding%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Well, I don't know. This code is somewhat weird, and you're using tables for your structure, and you use `<code>` tags to display this. Also, you said you're using the HTML editor for Wordpress, meaning you created this page, and appended the scripts to it in the HTML editor, correct? I would offer a different solution. Also I don't see any `<p>` tags wrapping your code created by your editor, so that leads me to assume that you're using a `nowrap` method of some sort, can i see this too?

Comment: there is extra double quotes in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a negative bottom margin to the buttons in question and it removed/reduced the space between the DIVs to just what I needed. That being said, if adding negative bottom margins is bad practice, someone feel free to jump in on this post and stop me!

ShaunOReilly, thanks so much for your help and the jsfiddle - I'll definitely keep it in mind.

Marca

Answer (score 0):

There is some extra double quotes between the buttons:

```
<div id="landing" style="margin-top: -100px; top: 50%; position: absolute; margin-left: -200px; left: 50%; "><div style="font-family: 'serif6_beta_rregular'; font-size: 26pt; color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">Adrienne Adams</div>
    ""
    <div class="sample" onclick="top.location.href='http://www.google.com'" style="background-color: rgb(35, 31, 32); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ">Main Site</div>
    ""
    ​<div class="sample" onclick="top.location.href='http://www.google.com'" style="background-color: rgb(35, 31, 32); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ">Mobile</div>​
    ""
    <div class="sample" onclick="top.location.href='http://www.google.com'" style="background-color: rgb(35, 31, 32); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ">Donate</div>​
</div>
```

It could be some new line characters or something.

This one seems to look different: http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/tHwmH/3/

When I add the same double quotes, I get the same effect: http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/tHwmH/4/

If you do not feel like spending days on trying to figure out why the template is doing what it is doing, then add the following jQuery to the `DocumentReady` function:

```
jQuery("#landing").parent().append("<div class='temp'><div>");
jQuery(".temp").append(jQuery("#landing div"));
jQuery("#landing").empty();
jQuery("#landing").append(jQuery(".temp div"));
jQuery(".temp").remove();
```

As seen in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/tHwmH/18/

Comment: ShaunOReilly, I've noticed those quotes too-the odd thing is they aren't there in the wordpress HTML editor-they just show up after I update the page and inspect it in Chrome. I'm wondering if either WP or the base theme I'm using (Atahualpa) could be creating them somehow?

Comment: I will dig into it more. Have you got the source of the theme / template?

Comment: Maybe just rip it out with jQuery for now, until you can figure out what it is doing...

Comment: I've seen that is doable, but I'm not sure how, exactly...do you know of a good JSfiddle or script that could strip the quotes?

Comment: Look at the last 5 lines of my answer! And example at: http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/tHwmH/18/